# How to change the metavar value for nargs=* in argparse?

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-arguments, argparse

I want to change the value that comes after -args option in the help message to "arg1 arg2 .." instead of "[arg [arg ...]]".

I've tried changing the metavar value but it only changes the output to "[arg1 arg2 ... [arg1 arg2 ... ...]]".

Here is my code:-

```
arg_parser.add_argument('-args', action='store', default=None, nargs='*' ,dest='arg',
                        help = "arguments passed to the program.")
```

and the exact output is :-
`-args [arg [arg ...]] 
                        arguments passed to the program.`

the output that I want:-
`-args [arg1 arg2 ..]  arguments passed to the program`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make `args` a positional argument instead of optional by removing the `-`:

```
parser.add_argument('args', nargs='*',
    help = "[arg1 arg2 ..] arguments passed to the program.")
```

Since your `nargs` is set to `*`, this doesn't really change anything in terms of when the commandline can be processed succesfully or not.

The list of optional values (`[arg [arg ...]]`) is not displayed for positional arguments, only the name. Using `help` as above to put in your custom text then gets you want you want:

```
positional arguments:  
  args        [arg1 arg2 ..] arguments passed to the program.
```

Answer (score 0):

Using 'metavar=('arg1', 'arg2')', a tuple, should display

```
[arg1 ... [arg2 ...]]
```

The [] and ... are fixed for '*'.  'nargs=2' produces the simpler display.

Beyond that you have to subclass the Formater and do surgery.